# Exposing a C symbol containing an array of strings from Rust to C

Tags: rust, ffi

I have the following C code:

```
const char * const Vmod_Spec[] = {
    "example.hello\0Vmod_Func_example.hello\0STRING\0STRING\0",
    "INIT\0Vmod_Func_example._init",
    0
};
```

After compiling a `.so` from this code I can load this symbol with `dlsym` and get the contents of `Vmod_Spec` and iterate over it. How can I achieve the same result exposing a symbol like this one from Rust?

Comment: The [FFI chapter in The Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html) specifies how to use FFI in Rust. The type would be `*const libc::c_char`.

Comment: I'm using i8(which is the type c_char is mapped to), the problem is that the only way I found to make it visible as a symbol is to define it as a `static` value, but I couldn't find a way to define a `static` value equivalent to this C's `char *` array

Comment: `extern {static Vmod_Spec: *const i8}`?

Comment: This doesn't work too, I get an error saying that `*const i8` doesn't implement the `Sync` trait then it can't be shared across threads(the compiler assumes that if it's being exposed it should be thread-safe). I also can't implement `Sync` for `*const i8` because I don't own any of these types. I'll be trying to wrap `*const i8` in another struct and implement `Sync` for it to see if the exported symbol is C compatible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rust equivalent for this would be exposing a `[*const c_char;3]` as an `static` value. The problem is that if you declare your value like this you will get an error: `error: the trait core::marker::Sync is not implemented for the type *const i8 [E0277]`. And you can't implement this trait for `*const c_char` because you don't own this type. The workaround was to declare a wrapper type around `*const c_char` and use it instead:

```
struct Wrapper(*const c_char)
unsafe impl Sync for Wrapper { }
#[no_mangle]
pub static Vmod_Spec: [Wrapper; 3] = etc..
```

And then I'll have a `Vmod_Spec` symbol which points to an array of values.